# How do I display an arrow for MKPinAnnotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView, like in Apple Maps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

Do I just initialize a button with an image similar to that or are there any default values I can use?

[image]

```
MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinLocation"];
newAnnotation.animatesDrop = YES;
newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

Comment: you mean the disclosure button?

Comment: Yeah.. but the UIButton's disclosure button displays a question mark, I would like an arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the disclosure button with the following code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation
{   
    MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotation = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pinLocation"];

    newAnnotation.canShowCallout = YES;
    newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    //for custom button 
    UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btn setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn;

    //try this for custom image on callout accessory view
    newAnnotation.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];

    return newAnnotation;
}
```

Comment: It's displaying as a circle with an i in the middle.  I'm using iOS 8

Comment: See the screenshot above

Comment: then you would need a disclosure indicator or you need to implement a custom annotation view

Comment: Thanks, it works except the tap handler doesn't get triggered anymore:

      - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control

Comment: in that case create a button with custom image and provide that button to the view

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**:
You can show the disclosure button in swift 4.2 as given below:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? 
{

    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }

    if let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "") {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation
        return annotationView
    } else {
        let annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation:annotation, reuseIdentifier:"")
        annotationView.isEnabled = true
        annotationView.canShowCallout = true

        let btn = UIButton(type: .custom)
        btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow"), for: .normal)
        btn.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 30)
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
        btn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return annotationView
    }
}
```